# Entity Framework SaveChangesAsync blocking my UI?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await

```
private async void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext();

                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                {
                    context.Table1.Add(new Table1() { Name = "jon" + i});
                }

                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            }
        }
```

in this code, context.SaveChangesAsync blocking my UI until Saving all records in database.
Why is this happening?
How do i fix it?

Update:

```
private async void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                context.Table1.Add(new Table1() { Name = "jon" + i });
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Start");
            await Task.Delay(20000);
            MessageBox.Show("End");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
    }
```

Why in the above code UI not blocking until delay ends?
But in the previous code UI is blocked?

Comment: Pause the debugger during the hang and post a screenshot of the call stack window.

Comment: Are you sure it's that line and not the loop above, or the `MyDbContext` constructor?

Comment: @DanielKelley
yes,i sure.

Comment: If you are still interested in this question, and from your edit it seems that way, you should post the information requested. Don't just ignore comments. Closing for now.

Comment: which provider? Using System.Data.SQLite for example all Async methods are just being executed in a blocking way.

Answer (score 0):

It is the code above the `await` line which is causing the problems.

Try this:

```
private async void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext();

                    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                    {
                        context.Table1.Add(new Table1() { Name = "jon" + i });
                    }

                    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            }
        }
```

This will make all the code run asynchronously and should not block the UI anymore. You can try debugging the `for loop` and `MyDbContext` lines and see why they're taking more time than they should.

Comment: Can you explain why the line is blocking? As far as I am aware it should keep the UI responsive.

Comment: I don't have access to your machine or setup so I am only speculating on the cause. But by looking at the code the only line which is actually doing anything asynchronous is the `await context.SaveChangesAsync();`.

All the other lines are still run on the UI thread and if they take long time to execute they will make the UI hang. By wrapping all that code in a `Task` you are forcing all of it to execute asynchronously and allowing the UI to run freely while this is executing in the background.

Comment: I'm not the one who raised the issue. I was just curious how you came to that conclusion.

Comment: Ohh sorry didn't pay attention to the username, does that make sense though? Asynchronous programming can get a bit mind boggling

Comment: why await Task.Delay(20000); not blocking UI?

Comment: `await` won't block the UI, it will only stall the execution of the rest of the function until the Task is finished. The rest of the app will continue processing while the `await` statement is waiting

Comment: This will work, however, it is a bad practice. Task.Run() is usually used for CPU-Bound tasks not for IO-bound tasks like database transactions

Answer (score 0):

This is mentioned in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/async):

> SQLite doesn't support asynchronous I/O. Async ADO.NET methods will execute synchronously in Microsoft.Data.Sqlite. Avoid calling them.

This includes EF Core. You can somewhat work around this with Task.Run:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        context.Table1.Add(new Table1() { Name = "jon" + i });
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
});

var items = await Task.Run(() =>
{
    MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext();

    context.ToList();
});
```

Comment: This will work, however, it is a bad practice. `Task.Run()` is usually used for CPU-Bound tasks not for IO-bound tasks like database transactions